# Compile replacement for Python's re.sub before the loop

Tags: python, python-re

I have trivial code to replace substrings using Python's `re` :

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(--type-header )([^ ]*)')
for x in somelist:
    filename = '...'  # here is a filename
    switches = x.replace('alice', 'bob')  # simple string
    switches = pattern.sub(
        r'\1' + f'{os.path.dirname(filename)}/' + r'\2',
        switches
    )
```

The substring I'd like to replace:

```
--type-header cond_enum_04.h
```

Everything works like a charm on Linux/macOs. But on Windows I get:

> re.error: bad escape \c at position 16

for about **250** iteration of the loop (249 iterations are successful). I suspect that this is a distinctive feature `re` in loops under the Windows. Is there some way to compile the replacement before entering the loop?

Comment: If the problem was in the search string, you could use `re.escape()` to make an arbitrary string safe from any misinterpretation - but it doesn't do quite the right thing for the replacement string, and there doesn't seem to be any equivalent function to handle that case.  So you're going to need to do the escaping yourself - replace all backslashes with double backslashes in the replacement string, before passing it to `re.sub()`.

Comment: Just speculating, but the problem may be related to how the Windows path is being parsed... so I the suggestion by @jasonharper might work, or possibly make `filename` a raw string as well, or maybe use pathlib with something like `Path(filename).parent`.  The full trace back may be helpful, or an actual example of the value for `filename`.

Comment: @BrianLarsen, "make `filename` a raw string" is not a meaningful thing to do.  The 'r' prefix only affects interpretation of backslashes in string literals, not backslashes that are already in a string variable.  Pathlib wouldn't help either, as the result is still going to be a string that has backslashes in it.

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks for the feedback.  Perhaps `Path(filename).parent.as_posix()` might give the desired behavior?  I still think it would help to have a bit more detail about the actual values for filename causing the issue and the full traceback.

Comment: @BrianLarsen Your suggestion does the trick. In the code sample above `filename` contained Windows directory separator `\\` interpreted as a regex escape command. Could you transform your comment to answer so that I'll able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the directory separator on Windows being interpreted as an escape character (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#:%7E:text=The%20backslash%20(%5C)%20character%20is%20used%20to%20escape%20characters%20that%20otherwise%20have%20a%20special%20meaning%2C%20such%20as%20newline%2C%20backslash%20itself%2C%20or%20the%20quote%20character.)).

One possible solution is to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to handle the path, and call its `.as_posix` method to render the path string in a consistent format across the various platforms, suitable then for applying the regex.

So in this case, replacing this:

```py
f'{os.path.dirname(filename)}/'
```

with something like this:

```py
f'{Path(filename).parent.as_posix()}/'
```